# Using nested router-outlets in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nested-routes, router-outlet

Im using multiple router-oulets to load my components.
The outer router-outlet is used load most basic components like login, home, 404.
I used nested router-outlet to load sub components of home page. That router-outlet is nested inside the home.component.

**home.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet name="homeRoute"></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    {path: '', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'homeRouter'},
    {path: 'user', component: UserComponent, outlet: 'homeRouter'},
    {path: 'user/:id', component: UserdetailComponent, outlet: 'homeRouter'}
  ]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginformComponent},
  {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}
];
```

HomeComponent and LoginformComponent need to loaded from the outer router-outlet.
Home component contains inner router-outlet with name 'homeRouter', which I want to use to load sub components of the home page.
But navigation of inner router wont work. I tried to access each component using router.navigate() method and using URL. But both of them did not work as expected.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code. I examined and tried few previous questions about the same problem but none worked fine.

Here are the URLs i tried for different components

1. `http://localhost:4200`   dashboardComponet (this one works)
2. `http://localhost:4200/user`  userComponent (doesnt work. routes to notFoundComponent)
3. `http://localhost:4200/user/U001`  userDetailComponent (doenst work.still route to notFoundComponent)

Comment: there is a typo name="homeRoute" outlet: 'homeRouter'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you do not need  named router-outlet for nesetd routes, you can remove `outlet: 'homeRouter'` from the Routes and `name="homeRoute"` from router-outlet and it should work.

Having said that, if you have  requirement for multiple router-outlet so that you can load an auxilary route along with primary route, the name of `router-oulet` should be same as `outlet` property.  in the Routes which you are using you have outlet: "**homeRouter**" and  name="**homeRoute**", they should be same.

Here is a complete example with multi level nested routes,

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6hkmRkGAIj9X0IA3oWVY?p=preview)

```js
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello</h1>
  <a routerLink="/" >Home</a>
   <a routerLink="/admin" >Admin</a>
    <a routerLink="/nonexistingroute" >Non existing Route</a>
  <hr />
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Component({
    template: `<h1>Home</h1>
   <a routerLink="/" >Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/users" >Users</a>
  <hr />
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `<h1>Admin</h1>
  `
})
export class AdminComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `<h1>Dashboard</h1>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `<h1>Users</h1>
  <a routerLink="user/1" >User 1</a>
  <a routerLink="user/2" >User 2</a>
  <hr />
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class Users { }

@Component({
    template: `<h1>User {{id}}</h1>
  `
})
export class UserdetailComponent {
    id = '';
    constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = params.id;
        });
    }
}

@Component({
    template: `<h1>Not found</h1>
  `
})
export class NotfoundComponent { }

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
            {
                path: 'users', component: Users,
                children: [
                    { path: 'user/:id', component: UserdetailComponent }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent
    },
    { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, AdminComponent, NotfoundComponent, DashboardComponent, Users, UserdetailComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Sorry. It's a mistake in my question. I removed the router name and outlet property from routes. Now i can load dashboard component. But other component cannot be loaded. What should I do???

Comment: How are you tryung to load other routes, can you update your question with the same?

Comment: Glad, I could help, you may accept the answer. Cheers!!

Comment: But how does the router recognize which router-outlet we are using when we try to load a component without router-outlet names and outlet properly at the app.module.ts. I thought router outlet is acting as an ID to recognize which router-outlet we are referring when we try to load a component. Can you please explain this to me...

Comment: Angular has a very effective route matching logic, it creates a hierarchical router tree when we load routes, so when ever we navigate to a route it loads respective component and checks the router-outlet to load n ested routes, so in bove example it loads `AppComponent` for empty path, then loads `HomeComponent` in the outlet againb it sees `router-outlet` and finds there is a child empty route   so it loads `DashboardComponent`. similarly when admin url is hit it loads `AdminComponent` in the 1st level `router-outlet` as it is 1st level route. Cheers!!

Comment: There is a script load error in the Plunker, here is a working Plunker
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/fv1pNwsnJc8yuhYi?preview